# Filtering one DE with another

Tags: marketing-cloud

I feel like this should be obvious but am hitting a wall as a newbie. I've created two filtered DEs. One is people who have opened an email, one is who has clicked. I want to exclude the clickers from the opening list, but can't for the life of me work out how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you filtering these via Measures? What are you using to validate if clicked or opened in filter activity?

Comment: Hi, yes. I created measures for the DE. The measures are simply if someone has opened or clicked on specific emails.